# Is there a simple way to populate a Spinner with an ArrayList?

Tags: android, spinner

I have a bunch of ArrayLists filled with data. All I want to do is populate the spinners using the arraylists. In other SO questions people create their own Adapters and store the ArrayList as a field, but I don't need to do that.

I just want to populate the spinner. I don't think theres something this easy, but is there anything resembling

```
mySpinner.populate( myList );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the built-in [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html), you don't have to write a custom Adapter.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
// Fill list with strings
...

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

You don't specify what data types you are using, but it doesn't matter: you can easily change the ArrayAdapter's subtype to `<Integer>`, `<Double>`, or even a custom class `<Kittens>` (as long as you define the custom classes toString() method.)

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayAdapters` have an `add()` method to store things to its internal list.  No need to create your own.  Try something like this:

```
for(Object ob : yourArrayList)
    <arrayAdapter>.add(ob);
<arrayAdapter>.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I would change `Object` to be whatever collection your `List` is using.

Comment: this will only work if your arrayAdapter is created with a mutable data structure.